# Ruby on Rails iterate array result into query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Following were my output from the query:

```
unless @slug == 'all'
  @city = '' if @city.blank?
  @city = @city.gsub("-", " ")
  country = Country.where("lower(name) LIKE ?", "#{@city.downcase}")
  gon.country = country
  if country.present?

  end
  if @city.present?
    @products = @products.where("lower(city) LIKE ? or lower(country) like ? or lower(state) LIKE ?", "%#{@city.downcase}%", "%#{@city.downcase}%","%#{@city.downcase}%")
    @city_obj = City.where("lower(name) LIKE ?", "%#{@city.downcase}%").first
  end
end
```

Here `gon.country` return result as:

```
Object
countries
:
Array[2]
0
:
"california"
1
:
"san francisco"
```

How can I iterate the `countries` and pass it to get `@products` result?

Comment: why are you searching for cities in country's name?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways :

1. Iterate all country record and then add like query.

   ```
   @product = []
   country.each do |con|
     @products << @products.where("lower(city) LIKE ? or lower(country) like ? or lower(state) LIKE ?", "%#{con.downcase}%", "%#{con.downcase}%","%#{con.downcase}%")
   end
   ```
2. You can use ILIKE syntax of core sql. Which work like this :

   ```
   select * from table where value ilike any (array['%foo%', '%bar%', '%baz%']);

   # in your case
   country_array_with_percent = country.map {|con| "%#{con}%" }
   @products.where("name ILIKE ANY ( array[?] )", country_array_with_percent)
   ```

You can also make query chaining with or query, More details [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9052)

Comment: receive an error `NoMethodError (undefined method `downcase' for #<Creference:0x007fd1ecc5f308>):`